# Корректно ли так убирать GET из url

Tags: .htaccess

Мучает вопрос, корректно ли таким образом чистить url от GET параметров ? они мне не нужны т.к. они выглядят иначе и обрабатываются в обработчике роутинга

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1? [R=301,L]
```

Однако если вставить данную запись, то перестает работать единая точка входа

```
RewriteBase /Controllers/route/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) /Controllers/route/index.php?$1 [QSA,L]
```

т.е. URL меняется на Controllers/route/index.php

Не силен в htaccess, прошу рассудить и помочь